# Are ARIMA model residuals normally distributed

Tags: time-series, arima, residuals, normality-assumption, diagnostic

I am running the `ARIMA` model using python's package: `sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX`. I get the following results. As we can see, the normal distribution is a bit not smooth on the bottom left side. Does that say anything about my model? or should I consider my model well fit my data?

[image]

Comment: Normality of residuals is somewhat exaggerated as a condition for an *linear regression model* to be applied. Homoskedasticity and absence of serial correlation are much more important. This EDA on the residuals seems to confirm both so I am less worried about it... Maybe explore more why there is that spike almost half way in the trajectory...

Comment: @usεr11852 what do you mean in 'both'?

Comment: 1. Homoskedasticity and 2. absence of serial correlation.

Comment: The title does not make grammatical sense. Consider revising.